# External HDD disconnects

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

On a Win 8 machine, I've connected a Samsung 2TB external HDD via USB, and mapped it to erive T. However, it keeps 'dropping out' (?).

When I plug it in, it is recognized as volume T. After a while - not long - the drive disappears. I have to unplug it, and then plug it back in.

I did not experience this issue on my previous pc, running Win XP.

When unplugging the drive, Win 8 makes the 'disconnecting' sound, yet it does not appear in 'Safely remove Hardware...' system tray popup menu.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, as I backup a database dump to this drive using a Scheduled Task - and it fails every day. :(

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have any idea! Didn't know a USB external HDD did that. How could i find out pls?

Comment: I guess that's not it. Once it 'disappears', it does NOT show up in Explorer, or My Computer, etc.

I do have mapped drives to other computers, and yes, I note that sometimes I have to actually click on the mapped drive for Windows to actually 'see' it, but that's not the case here. :(

Comment: No. I have a USB stick in one port, even renamed it in Win 8's 'My Computer', but it's 'connection' persists. However, that one is not explicitly mapped - it just gets the Windows allocated drive letter.

Comment: Wondering if it's a bug in the external HDD software... since it worked flawlessly in Win XP, but not in Win 8?

Comment: Does the external drive have its own power supply? If not, is it a special low power drive used in 2.5Inch external USB enclosures?  If not it simply might draw more power then the system is allowed to provide via USB.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked in XP and not in Win8 and you haven't done anything to the drive or external enclosure, then it's possibly a driver issue in which case I recommend browsing your external cases' manufactures website for the latest Win8 drivers. Otherwise it might be time to get a new external HDD case.

Comment: Hadn't even thought to do that. The external drive is only some 6-7 months old. As a 'dinosaur' programmer, I'd stayed with my very expensive, state-of-the-art Win XP box for a long time - till it got zapped by lightning a month ago. So my replacement machine dragged me kicking and screaming into Win 8.

Comment: As an update, it doesn't look like there is a firmware update. However, there are many issues online, regarding the G3 going to sleep, and not showing up in Explorer, so it can't be woken up.